# How to use stored procedure with table-valued parameters to compare two input tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I am trying to write a stored procedure to compute the differences between two input tables.

Stored procedure is used to calculate differences between two tables (both tables have the same predefined table structure), the stored procedure will provide records added, removed or updated when comparing table 1 to table 2.

**Example:**

- table 1 New has 3 records: A, B and C
- table 2 has 3 records: B', C and D

B' denotes a change to one or multiple fields within the record B

The output of this stored procedure call will be

```
A-addition  
B-update  
D-Removal
```

I have written a query to compute the difference between two tables, but finding it hard to translate to stored procedure.

Table structure:

```
X varchar (10)
Y int
Z datetime


SELECT 
    table1.*, ChangeType = 'Addition'
FROM 
    table1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM table2
                WHERE table1.x = table2.x)

UNION ALL

SELECT  
    table2.*, ChangeType = 'Removal'
FROM 
    table2
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM table1
                WHERE table1.x = table2.x)

UNION ALL

SELECT   
    table1, ChangeType = 'Update'
FROM 
    table2
INNER JOIN
    table1 ON table1.x = table2.x
WHERE 
    table1.Y <> table2.Y OR table1.Z <> table2.Z
```

Please also include the stored procedure execution script as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the MERGE sentence. You can put table1 as target and table2 as source based on certain values and decide what to do in case the match or not: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

In your case it would be something like:

```
MERGE table1 AS target  
USING table2 AS source (x, y, z)  
ON (target.x= source.x)  
WHEN MATCHED 
 --do something
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  
 --do something different
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
 --something else
```

As to how to receive a table as a parameter in a SP, you need to follow the next steps:

1. Create a DATA TYPE

   CREATE TYPE tableExample (X varchar (10),
   Y int,
   Z datetime)
2. Pass it to the SP:

   CREATE PROC sp_mysp @table1 tableExample, @table2 tableExample 
   AS ...

Comment: The question here is not about the table comparison logic, but around passing in the tables as table valued parameters in the first place, However suggestion to new comparison logic is welcomed.

Comment: so your question is "how do I pass a table as a parameter in a stored procedure?"

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer a single pass, using a case statement to classify the action.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CompareTables
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT    ChangeType = CASE
                           WHEN table2.x IS NULL THEN
                             'Addition'
                           WHEN table1.x IS NULL THEN
                             'Removal'
                           WHEN table1.Y <> table2.Y
                                OR table1.Z <> table2.Z THEN
                             'Update'
                           ELSE
                             'No Change'
                         END,
            table1.*,
            table2.*
  FROM  table2
    FULL OUTER JOIN table1
      ON table1.x = table2.x
  WHERE table2.x IS NULL
        OR  table1.x IS NULL
        OR  NOT ( table1.Y = table2.Y
                  AND   table1.Z = table2.Z
                );
END;
```

Comment: The question here is not about the table comparison logic, but around passing in the tables as table valued parameters in the first place, However suggestion to new comparison logic is welcomed.

Comment: Why do the tables need to be passed in as parameters?  Why can't they just be referenced directly by the SP?

Comment: Because the tables might not always be the same tables, I would like to allow for future changes. Hence writing a stored procedure.

Comment: 1. You should update your requirements above to indicate that table1 & table2 are table variables.
2. If the tables will always have the same definition, you'd be better off using persistent tables.
3. If the table defintions will change, you'll need to use dynamic sql to generate the columns and comparison sql
4. You can find more about passing @Table parameters to a SP here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx
5. In my opinion, this will be a headache to maintain.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but everywhere I looked, the example of table-valued parameter is used to update other tables.